# How do I get access to assets added to a library?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a main project and an external library. I have added a directory of assets to the external library in `src/assets/[50 files here]`.

When I do that, I go into the external library properties and select the folder and this includes all the files in that directory. Example shown (1 file selected):
[image]

In my main application I want to access that folder and copy the files into another directory. How do I access those files?

**Note**:

I may update these files periodically, copying the files and pasting them into that directory. There may be a few more or less files each time. So I'm against embedding them.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your main project `> Properties` and select `Flex Build Path`.  Under `Source path`, choose `Add Folder...` and enter the following

`${DOCUMENTS}\GigaLibrary\src\assets`

(assuming your library project is called GigaLibrary, that is)